# How to add a table of products with checkboxes in the Gravity Forms?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

How to add a table of products with checkboxes in the  Gravity Forms?

Products table
column 1 - sku
column 2 - product title
column 3 - checkbox

I want to make a table of products so that the user can select the desired products with checkboxes.
There are a lot of products, so need to fill them dynamically.

I looked at their documentation, did not find an example of how to add a table with checkboxes, or even my own html code that was written to the database correctly when sent.

help me please. Maybe someone has come across something similar.

Comment: Hi Natasha.  These kind of questions are better asked on a Gravity Forms forum.  This is a good one: https://www.facebook.com/groups/gravityforms. In the meantime, https://gravitywiz.com/checkbox-products-gravity-forms/